# Creating an Exchange dynamically spring boot rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

In my Application using rabbitmq with Spring boot -

How do i create an Exchange with ExchangeType defined as properties in my spring boot application.
 I see RabbitAdmin/AmqpAdmin has a method "declareExchange" but no option to declare ExchangeType.

I can put some conditions to check if else endif to create it based on property value but want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can declare the exchange names and the routing keys in your application.properties file and use **@ConditionalOnProperty** to conditionally create the exchanges and bindings beans as follows:-

```
@Configuration
class AMQPConfig {
    
    
    //the following beans creates Queues & Exchanges & Bindings programmatically

    
    @Bean
    public Queue queue(@Value("${my-queue}") String queueName) {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my-direct-exchange")
    DirectExchange directExchange(@Value("${my-direct-exchange}") String exchangeName) {
        return new DirectExchange(exchangeName);
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my-direct-exchange")
    Binding directExchangeBinding(Queue queue, DirectExchange directExchange,
            @Value("${direct-exchange-routing-key}") String routingKey) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(directExchange).with(routingKey);
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my-topic-exchange")
    TopicExchange topicExchange(@Value("${my-topic-exchange}") String exchangeName) {
        return new TopicExchange(exchangeName);
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "my-topic-exchange")
    Binding topicExchangeBinding(Queue queue, TopicExchange topicExchange,
            @Value("${topic-exchange-routing-key}") String routingKey) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(topicExchange).with(routingKey);
    }
    
}
```

**application.properties**

```
my-queue=rates
my-direct-exchange=my-direct-exchange
my-topic-exchange=my-topic-exchange
direct-exchange-routing-key=rates.euro
topic-exchange-routing-key=rates.*
```

if you commented **my-direct-exchange** property in the properties file, then the direct exchange and it's binding will not be created.

Comment: Yes, i can do that but it just makes code look ugly. I feel they should have created Exchange class to create any type of Exchange with existing Exchange interface called AbstractExchange.  Right now if i create the Exchange using if else conditions under one Bean, my BindingBuilder can only be configured with returning type GenericArgumentsConfigurer instead of Binding.  So basically i need to create Bindings also using multiple if else option or as you suggested. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Hopefully spring boot can provide configuration properties to allow us to configure the exchange.